# Unable to Access MySql 8.0 Database from Remote Windows Server

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012, mysql-8.0

I have Installed `MySql 8.0` Version in a windows
 server and able to connect via WorkBench/MySql shell locally.

I would like to access MySql from a remote windows server.

Here are the things I have tried.

1) Created `root@%` user and `Grant` full access to the new user.
2) Created a new user as `test@'remoteserveripaddress'` and `Grant` full access to the user.
3) Opened port `3306` on Both Remote and MySql server.
4) Added `"bind_address=*"` in `my.ini` file and restarted the `MySQL80` Service.

I am running out of options.

Error: I am getting below error

```
Failed to connect MySql at UserName@hostipaddress:3306 
SSL connection error: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
```

No matter how many different ways I try.

Not sure what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: not using the ssh tunnel as a more secure mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute below command in your terminal :

```
mysql -h server -P 3306 -u root -p
```

If you successfully connect to your database, the same thing has to happen with Mysql Workbench.

If you are unable to connect then I think `3306` port is acquired by another process.

Find which process running on `3306` port. If required, give admin privileges using `sudo`.

```
netstat -lnp | grep 3306
```

Kill/stop that process and restart your MySQL server. You are good to go.

Execute the below command to find my.cnf file.

```
mysql --help | grep cnf
```

You can change `MySQL` port to any available port in your system. But after that, make sure you restart `MySQL` server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I have missed major information in my question. I am using windows servers (both Host and Remote Servers).